# Multi Dimensional Array response.Reduce(minimize) Nested Loops

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.7

facebook Batch request api gives me the response.and as according to my logic this is the best response i get i want to access the root element "**source_id**" and "**copied_id**" inside the [BODY].
i just want to access them in minimum loops.

i am currently using nested loops.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [code] => 200
                [body] => {"copied_adset_id":"15454","ad_object_ids":[{"ad_object_type":"ad_set","source_id":"545454","copied_id":"15454"}]}
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [code] => 200
                [body] => {"copied_adset_id":"1547754","ad_object_ids":[{"ad_object_type":"ad_set","source_id":"566454","copied_id":"1547754"}]}
            )
     )
 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [code] => 200
                [body] => {"copied_adset_id":"1500454","ad_object_ids":[{"ad_object_type":"ad_set","source_id":"598754","copied_id":"1500454"}]}
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [code] => 200
                [body] => {"copied_adset_id":"78448","ad_object_ids":[{"ad_object_type":"ad_set","source_id":"541230","copied_id":"78448"}]}
            )
     ))
```

The body contain the JSON response below is the decoded json response.

```
stdClass Object(
[copied_adset_id] => 14848
[ad_object_ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ad_object_type] => ad_set
                [source_id] => 14848
                [copied_id] => 448486
            )

    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code hope this will help you

```
foreach($arraya as $arrayaresponse) {    
    foreach($arrayaresponse as $copiedarray) {    
        $adsetdata = array();    
        $copiedBody = json_decode($copiedarray - > body);    
        $adata['source_id'] = $copiedBody - > ad_object_ids[0] - > source_id;   
        $adata['copied_id'] = $copiedBody - > ad_object_ids[0] - > copied_id;   
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor it to use Collections since you are using Laravel.

For example:

```
$response = [
    [
        (object) [
            'code' => 200, 
            'body' => '{"copied_adset_id":15454,"ad_object_ids": [{"ad_object_type":"ad_set","source_id": 545454,"copied_id": 545}]}'
        ],
        (object) [
            'code' => 200, 
            'body' => '{"copied_adset_id":15454,"ad_object_ids": [{"ad_object_type":"ad_set","source_id": 545454,"copied_id": 545}]}'
        ]  
    ],
    [
        (object) [
            'code' => 200, 
            'body' => '{"copied_adset_id":15454,"ad_object_ids": [{"ad_object_type":"ad_set","source_id": 545454,"copied_id": 545}]}'
        ],
        (object) [
            'code' => 200, 
            'body' => '{"copied_adset_id":15454,"ad_object_ids": [{"ad_object_type":"ad_set","source_id": 545454,"copied_id": 545}]}'
        ]  
    ]  
];

return collect($response)
    ->flatten()
    ->flatMap(function($item) {
        return json_decode($item->body, true)['ad_object_ids'];
    })
    ->map(function($item) {
        return array_only($item, ['source_id', 'copied_id']);
    })
    ->toArray();
```

The output of the above will be:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "source_id" => 545454
    "copied_id" => 545
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "source_id" => 545454
    "copied_id" => 545
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "source_id" => 545454
    "copied_id" => 545
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "source_id" => 545454
    "copied_id" => 545
  ]
]
```

Here's an [example](https://implode.io/fTavT4) you can play around with.